# A sequential function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am interested in verifying the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) for simulated data. My thoughts were to generate a vector of observations and take the sample mean sequentially, that is first for 1 observation, then for 2,3,...,n. To that end I have written down the following function:

```
n <- 10000
x <- rnorm(n)
xn <- function(n) {
   xn <- mean(x[1:n])
   list(xn) 
}
```

Then I would like to plot the sample means versus n for n=1,...,n but unfortunately I do not quite know how to do that. I have been (naively) trying the code:

```
y <- c(1:n)
plot(y, xn(y))
```

and this is the error I have been getting

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:n : numerical expression has 1000 elements: only the first used
```

Can you please help me with that last part?

Comment: have a look at http://www.r-bloggers.com/weak-law-of-large-numbers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben Bolker's solution is more efficient, but here is how you would fix your original code.
The problem is that your function takes one element rather than a vector/list of elements, so you have to use `sapply` to apply it to every element in `y`.

```
n <- 10000
x <- rnorm(n)
xn <- function(n) {
    xn <- mean(x[1:n])
}
y <- 1:n
plot(y, sapply(y, xn))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can efficiently compute the 'cumulative mean' via the `cumsum()` function, followed by vectorized division by `1:n`:

```
n <- 10000
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(n)
cx <- cumsum(x)
cm <- cx/(1:n)
plot(1:n,cm,type="l")
```